# How to pass parameters received by my function to a class created inside my function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, appium, python-unittest

I am developing a program with Python 3.7 and Appium 1.15

The program will run parallel test on real Android devices. I need to pass parameters to the function which will run the test on a specific smartphone.

These parameters are the desired capabilities (udid, os version, devicename, etc….).

So my idea was to create a method in myownmodule.py which will receive the parameters and pass it to the Class object.
The best way to explain my idea is to share my code:

```
def Task_auto1(p_name_action,p_udid, p_systemPort, p_deviceName, p_version, p_os,quantity_tasks_per_hit):


   class auto1(unittest.TestCase):
       def setUp(self):
           print(f"--------- Start {p_name_action} for Smartphone N° {p_udid} --------------")

           desired_caps = {}
           desired_caps['automationName'] = 'UiAutomator2'
           desired_caps['platformName'] = p_os
           desired_caps['platformVersion'] = p_version
           desired_caps['deviceName'] = p_deviceName
           desired_caps['udid'] = p_udid
           desired_caps['noReset'] = 'true'
           desired_caps['appWaitActivity'] = 'com.app1.activity.MainTabActivity'
           desired_caps['autoGrantPermissions'] = 'true'
           desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.app1.app'
           desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.app1.app.activity.MainTabActivity'
           desired_caps['systemPort'] = p_systemPort
           desired_caps['chromeDriverPort'] = p_systemPort
           self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
           self.driver.start_activity("com.app1.app", "com.app1.app.activity.MainTabActivity")

       def tearDown(self):
           self.driver.quit()

       def test_auto1(self):
        #do some stuff
        pass

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(auto1)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

But I have no idea how to pass the parameters received by my function to my test Class and method.

I search on Google and I couldn’t find the answer to my question. I typed “python pass parameters from my function to a class inside my function”, but it doesn’t give me the accurate answer.

A second problem may come, I need this unittest test running properly Appium test.

If some expert could help the newbie I am to find solution to this complex programming issue, please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If parameters are configuration parameters, they are fixed. I'd keep parameters in a json file or any text file and read them in test case, I believe for each test input you will need too write a validation case.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Parameters are not fixed as code will run on multiple devices at same time. So each series of parameters are variable.

Comment: Unit testing is effective only when you know what input parameters are passed, so that you know what is the out come expected. In your example, I can see you are starting a web driver with dynamic parameters, then it would be difficult to validate what is expected. So, run your code which generates all these parameters, there are only handful of them, put them in a file or in a map in ```setup``` function or anywhere else, then write assertions in say ```test_webdriver_invalid_device_name()```, since you are creating a process(webdriver), I suggest create them in test_<your_test> function.